# Login freeze on Ubuntu 18.04 + can't bring up shell (Ctrl + F2)

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, shortcut-keys, login

I know there are multiple threads on login freeze and the fixes that I found require the user to run shell and download some drivers. **My problem is that I can't open the shell** because either the freeze happens before I even try to log in, or, if it doesn't happen instantly, then none of the key combinations work for me. I tried Ctrl + Alt + F1-F6, and tried Ctrl + Alt + Fn + F1-F6 as well. Nothing happens. And then the freeze happens. I would appreciate any hints because I'm at a loss as to what to do now.

I've got a Dell Inspiron 7567 i7-7700HQ with NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050Ti graphic card. I have a Windows 10 installed and have just completed my Ubuntu 18.04.2 installation alongside Windows.

Comment: Does Windows work OK? For Ubuntu, hit "e" at the GRUB screen, find "quiet splash" and change it to "quiet splash nomodeset", control-x to continue boot. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema Yes, Windows works just fine. Your solution worked, I think. I was able to log into Ubuntu, download drivers for my nvidia card, and after some configuration that involved enrolling MOK, and a reboot, I was able to log into Ubuntu the "normal" way. So far so good. Thank you!

Comment: Let me put together a quickie answer that you can accept, ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

I suspected a potential problem with the Nvidia video driver in Ubuntu. Windows worked fine.

I had the user edit the GRUB startup to include `nomodeset`, which effectively disables the Nvidia drivers, and will allow the user to update the Nvidia driver.

The user was able to download and install new/current Nvidia drivers, did some configuration, and enrolled MOK, and after a reboot, it all worked fine! Yeah!